# Configuration error. Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] not found while connecting to DB

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jpa, derby

I am using the command `mvn exec:java` to run my application from `cmd`.My Persistence.xml properties are is :

```
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:DB;create=true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

        <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
            value="database" />
        <property name="connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
    </properties>
```

and my pom.xml dependency and build properties are :-

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-framework</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.18</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

if the run the main class in `eclipse` using `run as java application` it runs fine but using the command `mvn exec:java` gives the error of Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing library with `Derby` driver in your `pom.xml`.
Try to add this in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.11.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In eclipse it is running probably because you added the driver manually to classpath.

Comment: Worked fine with dependency of  `derby` only.

Comment: derbyclient is for a connection URL which uses the client-server driver, derby is for a connection URL which uses the embedded driver. Since the persistence.xml specifies the embedded driver, derby is the correct artifactid to use.

Answer (score 18):

For anyone having trouble with Derby:
Now (as of version *10.15.2.0*), their Driver is `org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver`.

Comment: I can´t give 100 points for this answer, this page only allows one point per user, but I want to let you know how useful your answer is.

Comment: I had to use `org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver` found in derbyclient.jar.