# JDBC connection to derby in java method

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, derby

I'm trying to create a simple java method to create a connection to a Derby db created in Netbeans.  The db was named group1 with user/pass of group1/group1.  The database is connected when I look at the services tab.  I am calling this method from a jsp and i am getting the exception handled message instead of actually creating a connection.  Below is my method... right now it returns a success or fail message, but will later be used within other methods to create the connection prior to executing queries or updates.  I have imported "java.sql.*" to handle the connection and other sqly things and my connection "conn" is defined earlier in the java class. Any advice as to why would be so greatly appreciated.

```
public static String createConnection(){
String result;
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/group1","group1","group1");
        result="connection successful";
    } catch (Exception noConnection) {
        System.err.println("Connection Failed!");
        result="connection failed";
    } // end connection try-catch
return result;
} // end createConnection method
```

Comment: What is the exact message given by noConnection.getMessage() ?

Comment: add a `noConnection.printStackTrace()` to you catch block, and post the stacktrace here.

Comment: Even better, capture the entire nested exception chain: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: @BryanPendleton, I'll do that as soon as I get back to my laptop to see what the error reads.  My Tomcat 8 server doesn't provide any extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your driver class isn't the most suitable here, give a try to this one instead :

```
org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using a different driver class
Use client driver instead

[Configuration error. Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] not found while connecting to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071037/configuration-error-class-org-apache-derby-jdbc-embeddeddriver-not-found-whil)

Answer (score -1):

```
Connection con= <ClassName>.createConnection();
```

Try this code in your main method hope it will run.

If not then check that either you have configured derby jar file in your library or not.